# Swift & Firebase - Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Swift with Firebase and I am a little bit confused with this error : `Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x122ab6130) to 'Repeat.Expression' (0x1100004c0).`

Here is a sample of the JSON file I use :

```
{
  "levels" : {
    "level1" : {
      "coverImage" : "lvl1",
      "expressions" : [ {
        "expression" : "Yes",
        "id" : 0
      }, {
        "expression" : "Yes",
        "id" : 1
      }, {
        "expression" : "Yes",
        "id" : 2
      }, {
        "expression" : "Yes",
        "id" : 3
      } ],
      "id" : 0,
      "title" : "Essentiel"
    },
    "level2" : {
      ...
    },
  }
}
```

Here are the two models I use :

```
struct Level {
    let id : Int
    let coverImage : String
    let title : String
    let expressions : [Expression]
}

struct Expression {
    let id : Int
    let expression : String
}
```

Finally, here is the function I use to fetch the levels :

```
var levels = [Level]()

func fetchLevels() {

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("levels").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                if let levelId = dictionary["id"], let levelCoverImage = dictionary["coverImage"], let levelTitle = dictionary["title"], let levelExpressions = dictionary["expressions"] {
                    let level = Level(
                        id: levelId as! Int,
                        coverImage: levelCoverImage as! String,
                        title: levelTitle as! String,
                        expressions: levelExpressions as! [Expression]
                    )
                    self.levels.append(level)
                }


                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                  self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }


            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

It appears that the problem is at the line `expressions: levelExpressions as! [Expression]`

Thank you very much for your help.

Have a good day.

Comment: `levelExpressions` is an array of NSDictionaries, not of your Expression class; you need to explicitly create instances of `Expression` from the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
let levelExpressions = dictionary["expressions"]
```

The above line returns array of dictionaries i.e.`[[String:Any]]` and needs to require that value to be mapped into your struct Expression.This can be done in 2 ways:-

1) You can use [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)  to typecast the return value of above code.

2) Manually allocate the `Expression` object by parsing the return values of 
`let levelExpressions = dictionary["expressions"] as! [[String:Any]]` and assigning them to properties `id` and `expression`